# How can I set the laptop fan speed to 100% manually?

Tags: laptop, cooling, speedfan, fan

I would like to know if there is a way to set my laptop fan speed to 100%. I want something that I can assign a key to, so when I press combination of keys my fan speed will boost to 100% and pressing them again will reduce it to normal.

I know the question has been asked before but the solutions recommended aren't exactly what im looking for.

I know how to set the cooling to active/passive so dont bring that up.
Ive used speedfan so ignore that as well.
I dont want third part cooling pads or usb fans so dont mention that either. 
I just want something simple that lets me boost the speed and slow it down after.

Comment: which computer are you using? If it's a dell, try this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/controlling-dell-fan-speeds-temperature-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/

Comment: @polym I haven alienware M15x. It never overheats but I just want to set it up to use it occassionally when I like my laptop on my lap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need two softwares, one for controlling the fan speed, another for short keys.
http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php